# SQL get date month from query

Tags: sql

I have a datecolumn called invoicedate,

my query is:

```
select
    MONTH(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate) as datemonth,
    Year(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate)as dateYear
from
    dbo.tblInvoices
```

this return 9|2009 ect...

How do I get those to return as one string, as in one column not two?  output example: 9/2009

SQL server 2005

Comment: It depends on the database engine. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    Convert(varchar(2), MONTH(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate))
    + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), Year(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate)) as date
from
    dbo.tblInvoices

Select
    Convert(varchar(6), dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate, 112) As InvoiceYearMonth
From
    dbo.tblInvoices
```

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more formatting options.

Comment: Nearly works, but when you sort it, it only sorts by the all the characters up the first /

Comment: Updated the answer although now there is no / in between month and year. Do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(MONTH(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate), '/', Year(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate)) 
from dbo.tblInvoices
```

should do the trick that is assuming your using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Information retrieved using [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=sql%20concatenate&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=)

First return [SQL Concatenate Function](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html)

depends on your database engine...

- MySQL: CONCAT()
- Oracle: CONCAT(), ||
- SQL Server: +

**Example 1:**

**MySQL/Oracle:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(region_name,store_name) FROM Geography 
WHERE store_name = 'Boston';
```

**Result:**

'EastBoston'

**Example 2:**

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT region_name || ' ' || store_name FROM Geography 
WHERE store_name = 'Boston';
```

**Result:**

'East Boston'

**Example 3:**

```
SQL Server: 
SELECT region_name + ' ' + store_name FROM Geography 
WHERE store_name = 'Boston';
```

**Result:**

'East Boston'

Answer (score 0):

What flavour of SQL are you using here? Does `to_date(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate, 'MM/YYYY')` work?

As Patrick pointed out, it depends a lot on your database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the + symbol for concatenation for example

select
    MONTH(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate) + '/' +
    Year(dbo.tblInvoices.InvoiceDate) as date
from
    dbo.tblInvoices